# scope problems with events: What are good practices for avoiding inline Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, events, scope, prototype

I seem to be having scope issues with using `addEventListener` inside of an immediate anonymous function.

Inside of the event listener, I am creating an instance of a Javascript "class" that is constructed outside of the immediate function (using a constructor and `prototype`).

In trying to keep with good practices, I wanted to use the immediate function to avoid global variables, and `addEventListener` to avoid using inline Javascript (thus separating it from html).

So how can I correctly do this without having scope issues, and what are good practices for doing so?

---

Here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "userInput" />
        <input type = "button" id = "submitButton" value = "submit" />

            <script type = "text/javascript" src = "asdf.js" />
    </body>
</html>
```

...and here is my Javascript `asdf.js` (which is *not* working):

```
// constructor for object-oriented processing of the user input
function Statement(expression)
{
    this.expression = expression;
}
    // instance method
    Statement.prototype.checkSyntax = function()
    {
        var newExp = this.expression;

        return newExp;
    };

// immediate anonymous function
(function()
{   
    var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");

    // event listener for the submit button
    submitButton.addEventListener("onclick", function(event)
    {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");

        // creating a new object with constructor above
        var expr = new Statement(userInput);

        // calling instance method of the "class" Statement
        alert(expr.checkSyntax() );

        // disable the button after first use
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }, false);

})(); // end of immediate anonymous function
```

Comment: You can define the class inside of the immediate function, effectively creating a closed scope.

Comment: I don't see any scoping issues. What errors do you get?

Comment: I can't help but laugh about @Soupd'Campbells commenting on Ian _Cambell's_ question.  Letting your soup make comments on your own question seems questionable ;)

Comment: @jahroy ha, and I am literally eating soup right now, no lie.

Comment: Is it Campbell's soup or did you steal it? (Ok, I'll end my bad comedy routine)

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells nice name! But I tried to do that (defining the class inside of the immediate function), and that wasn't working either..

Comment: @jahroy I am eating Kroger brand Broccoli Cheddar soup... I am a traitor to my own family soup.

Comment: @IanCampbell: Yeah, it wasn't the only issue, but I was being dragged out the door for a cigarette and couldn't dig deeper. Not enough for a full answer, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addEventListener` takes an argument like `click`, not `onclick`. However, older IE's `attachEvent` requires `onclick`. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: There's one more thing: `var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput")` is missing `.value`.

Comment: @Kolink ah, `click` instead of `onclick`... this is odd, are other event arguments similar, such as `blur` instead of `onblur`?

Comment: @IanCampbell - I believe `onclick` is the name of the html attribute, whereas `click` is the name of the event type.  A little more info on [event types here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) and more info on [addEventListener here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Comment: `on_____` is used in the HTML attribute, the property (`Node.onclick = function() {...}`) and the old-IE `attachEvent`. Only `addEventListener` doesn't need it. It makes sense, since the first argument can only be an event name, but it does seem confusing.

Answer (score 1):

> my Javascript which is not working

There might be some issues, but none has to do with the (imho unnecessary) IEFE:

- `addEventListener` needs the event name without `"on"` - that's only M$ quirks in `attachEvent`.
- Make sure your JS executes after the DOM elements are created - otherwise `submitButton` will be `null`
- I guess you want to pass a string to the `Statement` constructor, not the `<input>` DOM node - use `userInput.value`

Comment: thanks for the help. If the IEFE (*Immediately-Invoked Function Expression*) is unneccessary, how might I do something similar to avoid global variables?

Comment: Ah, right, you did use it to avoid global variables (but did declare `Statement` globally). In your case, you could just omit the `submitButton` variable and directly `document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener(…)`

Comment: @IanCampbell You could alternatively add an anonymous function as an event listener for the DOM ready event. Also, IEFE is a good practice for protecting your functions and class definitions (which you aren't using it for at the moment), especially in cases where you might have third-party scripts or script-injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells Interesting, so should I encapsulate an entire .js file this way as a general good practice to prevent security issues?

Comment: @IanCampbell: No. If you don't trust third-party-scripts, do not include them. Wrapping all your files in IEFEs would not help against attacks. However, with the (revealing) module pattern often files consist only of one big IEFE.

Comment: @Bergi It's not always the developer's choice what third-party scripts are included.

Comment: @IanCampbell SOME security issues, specifically those related to external scripts (third-party or injected) overriding your classes and/or functions. For instance, if you had an AJAX request for sensitive data and you defined your callback function in the global scope, another script could redefine that function and hijack your sensitive data. IEFE is not a panacea, but it is useful towards the end of effective script security.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells That makes sense about the AJAX example. So being that it is a goal to avoid using global variables, is it equally a goal to then minimize global functions as well? Or should you be concerned only with functions that access sensitive data or communicate with the server? I have just started learning design patterns, so the module pattern Bergi mentioned is new to me...

Comment: There is no security through IEFEs. Malicious scripts could always hijack the necessary communication, both to the user (global DOM) and to the server (global Ajax interface). However, modularisation and avoiding globals are always good design patterns.

Comment: @Bergi - If you define your AJAX handler in an IEFE (mind you, not JQuery, because JQuery defines things in global scope) with callback functions also defined in the IEFE then there is no means by which a malicious script could hijack that commmunication *through javascript execution*. Do you still have a server-side ajax interface that can be abused? Yes. Can another script mimic your interaction with the server? Yes. Is it possible for another script to grab any data you insert into the DOM? Yes. Can another script interfere with the execution of yours by hijacking your callback? *No.*

Comment: Yeah, it might be possible, but you had to secure all globals that you use in your IEFE before the third-party script loads - it makes modularisation a pain. Think of `(function(origsend, callback){ XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(){callback(this);return origsend.apply(this, arguments);}; })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send, function(xhr){ console.log("Hijacked:",xhr); });`